# slideshow of forms by clicking dots on the right side of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on making a slideshow of forms. Here is my working [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwyoZj). As you can see I have two dots on the right side which if I click then it opens another form. Only thing is those dots are getting shown at the very bottom of my page. I want to show them actually on the form instead at the right side.

For example as shown in this [image](https://postimg.org/image/4isaog1mx/). I am trying to replicate exactly like this image and as you can see those dots are on the form instead but at the very right side of it close to the right border. Also `LAST NAME`, `PHONE NUMBER` , `PROVINCE` and `CITY` label and its textbox are just above those dots. I want to do something similar. Is this possible to do?

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
    }

    #slides,
    #slides2,
    #slides3 {
      display: none;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smartphones */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smaller displays like laptops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .container {
        width: 724px
      }
    }

    /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
   <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
               <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
         <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
         <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>  
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
   <h3>INSURANCE FORM</h3>
   <h4><i>BASIC DETAILS</i></h4>
   <br>    
    <div id="slides">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 1">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });

      /*
        To have multiple slideshows on the same page
        they just need to have separate IDs
      */
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
        start: 3,
        play: {
          auto: true
        }
      });

      $('#slides3').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now try this and u can see the demo here [Demo](https://codepen.io/Nitrick/full/LLpRGL/)

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
    }

    #slides,
    #slides2,
    #slides3 {
      display: none;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */


    /* For smartphones */

  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
   <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
               <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
         <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
         <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>  
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
   <h3>INSURANCE FORM</h3>
   <h4><i>BASIC DETAILS</i></h4>
   <br>    
    <div id="slides" class="container-fluid" >

  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 1">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>

   </form>

      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
      $('.form-horizontal').css('padding','0 45px 0 0')

      /*
        To have multiple slideshows on the same page
        they just need to have separate IDs
      */
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
        start: 3,
        play: {
          auto: true
        }
      });

      $('#slides3').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

and Style css

```
#slides {
  position: relative;
}
#slides .slidesjs-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%; right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
}
#slides .slidesjs-pagination li {
  float: none;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde Demi;
    src: url(AvantGarde Demi.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: ITC Avant Garde Gothic;
    src: url(ITC Avant Garde Gothic.woff);
}
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.topnav > img,
nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav > ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.topnav .dropdown {
/*    display: block;
    float: left; 
    text-align: center; */
}
.topnav a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topnav .dropdown > a {
    padding: 20px 16px;
}
.topnav .dropdown-content li > a {
    padding: 10px 16px;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul {
    background-color: #f76c38;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
body {
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.fa-6 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.login {
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    font-size: 11.433px;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.login a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.login a:hover {
    color: #fe5b1f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
li.insurance {
/*    padding-top: 30px !important; */
}
li.our-story {
/*    padding-top: 30px !important; */
}
li.login-signup {
/*    padding-top: 30px !important; */
}
li.get-covered {
/*    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important; */
}
li.our-story {
    color: white;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.login-signup {
    color: white;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.get-covered {
    border-color: #EF7440;
    border-style: solid;
    color: white;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.get-covered:hover {
    background-color: #EF7440;
}
li.insurance {
    color: white;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
}
.form-horizontal .form-control {
  border-radius:0;
  border:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid orange;
}
.form-horizontal .form-control:focus{
  box-shadow:none;
}
.container-fluid
{
  padding:0 !important;
}
.container
{
  padding:0 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for an update but still those dots are lying on labels and textbox. How can I make sure that form is just before those dots just like in the image I have.

Comment: Now check this will defiantly work and I have update that code pen demo.

Comment: I clicked that but in your code pen, now I don't see my form at all.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to update the link my bad now check it

Comment: cool now it works.. also do you know how we can get rid of lot of whitespaces that is there below my forms? I just need my header and my slideshow of form only on a particular page and nothing else.. As of now if I scroll down, it shows lot of whitespace below my form

Comment: let me see to it

Comment: Now check it I think this will work other wise use screen height to adjust the screen

Comment: hey Shortcut did this demo work for you then accept the answer man

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `top` value to less percentage, something like this and check

```
#slides .slidesjs-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

**Update**
As per the comment, if you want achieve the same design as in the image, try the following
Your forms `width` is set to `100%` change it to `width: 96%;` or something lesser than `100%` with the above style mentioned. **(Do the width change for both forms)**

Comment: yes but now it is lying actually on those labels and textbox. If you see my actual image, those labels and textbox are just before those dots and I exactly want to do that.. Basically I want to replicate exactly as it is there in the image.

Comment: did you applied the both styles? I checked it was working fine